# Comparar arquivos com PHP

Tags: php, versionamento, comparação, aplicação-web

Existe alguma ferramenta ou forma de criar uma comparação de arquivos com o PHP? Gostaria de algo parecido com o [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/features.php) mas dentro do Navegador.

Temos um sistema de controle de alterações em aplicações que desenvolvemos aqui, e esse sistema é web, aí queríamos criar algo que pudesse controlar quem foi e quais os arquivos de código fonte foram substituídos pelos programadores, mas como eles estão acostumados com o Beyond Compare gostaríamos de fazer algo parecido.

Comment: O que você tentou implementar até aqui ? Qual sua dúvida específica?

Comment: Qual é o problema de comparar os arquivos byte-a-byte? Ou o checksum/hash de ambos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Achei [esta classe aqui](http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/diff-implementation/) <sup>[*[mirror]*](https://gist.github.com/brasofilo/b8557d325a7bc4ab6b50)</sup> que implementa um Diff em PHP. Testei com um arquivo `.json` simples, fazendo uma cópia e deletando um objeto, o resultado é:

<kbd>[image: teste php diff]</kbd>

E este é arquivo PHP de teste:

```
<html><head>
    <style>
    .diff td{
      vertical-align : top;
      white-space    : pre;
      white-space    : pre-wrap;
      font-family    : monospace;
    }
    .diffUnmodified { background-color: #BAF4FA; }
    .diffDeleted { background-color: #EEB4B4; }
    .diffInserted { background-color: #A9F2A4; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    // output the result of comparing two files as a table
    <?php 
    require_once './class.Diff.php';
    echo Diff::toTable( Diff::compareFiles('calendar-1.json', 'calendar-2.json') ); 
    ?>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tem uma forma no exemplo #1 no manual PHP [`xdiff_file_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xdiff-file-diff.php) que faz diff unificado de dois arquivos PHP com comprimento contexto da 2.

```
<?php
$old_version = 'my_script.php';
$new_version = 'my_new_script.php';

xdiff_file_diff($old_version, $new_version, 'my_script.diff', 2);
?>
```

Lembrando que não serve para arquivos binários.